# What's the proper way to handle a KeyboardInterrupt during a subprocess that accepts "silent" input?

Tags: python, subprocess

With Python 3.11.4, when I use `subprocess.run` or `subprocess.Popen` to accept "silent" input or "secure input" and then hit ctrl+c, using regular `input` afterwards doesn't display text being typed. Here's a reproducible example:

```
import subprocess

try:
    print("hit ctrl+c")
    result = subprocess.run("echo $(read -s)", shell=True)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass

text = input("Text typed here is not visible: ")
print(text)
```

Here's my attempt, using Popen, to kill the process (but to no avail):

```
import subprocess

result = subprocess.Popen("echo $(read -s)", shell=True)
try:
    print("hit ctrl+c")
    result.wait()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    result.kill()
    pass

text = input("Text typed here is not visible: ")
print(text)
```

How do I go about properly ending the process waiting for silent input so that regular input afterwards is displayed as it's typed?

Edit: I should clarify that I'm building an interface which uses `subprocess` to interact with a specific command line tool. That tool prompts the user for input in a "silent" fashion, but I was able to reproduce the problem using `echo $(read -s)` in its place.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using a subprocess for this instead of the built-in `getpass` module?

Comment: @Barmar Apologies, I should have clarified that I'm using subprocess to query a command line tool that prompts the user for "silent" input. I've updated my initial post.

Comment: This is technically a bug in your command-line tool; it disables terminal echoing but doesn't re-enable it before exiting.

Comment: @chepner That very well could be the case. Using my contrived example, how would I go about re-enabling terminal echoing? If I can better understand that I'll have an easier time investigating a potential bug in the command-line tool I'm using.

Comment: The simplest solution would probably be to execute `reset`, but will also do things like change the current foreground and background colors back to the terminal default, if they've been changed. A more targeted solution would be to execute (I think) `stty echo`.

Comment: @chepner `os.sytem("stty echo")` works! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you might be looking for `getpass`?

```py
from getpass import getpass

getpass("Text typed here is not visible: ")
```

Comment: Apologies, as I mentioned in another comment I should have clarified that I'm using subprocess to query a command line tool that prompts the user for "silent" input. I've updated my initial post.